# Удаление файлов с Яндекс диска.API

Tags: c#, winforms, яндекс-диск

как удалять файлы с яндекс диска если доступны только методы загрузки и скачивания файлов

```
using YandexDisk.Client;

 var api = new DiskHttpApi(token);

 var rootFolderData = await api.MetaInfo.GetInfoAsync(new ResourceRequest
                {
                    Path = "/"
                });

api.Files.???
```

Comment: Судя по исходникам, методы удаления находятся в [ICommandsClient](https://github.com/raidenyn/yandexdisk.client/blob/72e4f68d8ecd57e5bfde77897760104eb3a63cdb/src/YandexDisk.Client/Clients/ICommandsClient.cs), который в свою очередь находится в [IDiskApi](https://github.com/raidenyn/yandexdisk.client/blob/72e4f68d8ecd57e5bfde77897760104eb3a63cdb/src/YandexDisk.Client/IDiskApi.cs). То есть, получаем в вашем случае следующее: `await api.Commands.DeleteAsync(...);`. Сам же метод принимает объект `DeleteFileRequest`, в котором указывается 2 значения `Path` и `Permanently` (не помещать в корзину).

Comment: https://yandex.ru/dev/disk/doc/dg/sdk/csharp.html А что, в документации ничего нет?